# What's the best way to automatically push a link to my phone?

Tags: android, google-chrome, pushbullet

I would to either write a script or utilize Chrome extensions to automatically push links to my Android.
I have Pushbullet installed which is great, but I have to manually push the links over using a keyboard shortcut. 
How might I go about automating this? Is there a way to push only certain URLs?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Are you pushing links from your chrome browser or from some other source?

Comment: @christopherhesse Well, the links originate from a scrapy/python script and automatically get inserted into the Chrome browser. Looking to basically extend my script for when I'm AFK. Chrome --> Phone is probably easiest, yeah?

Comment: If they're coming from a script, you can pretty easily call the pushbullet api to send a push to your phone: https://docs.pushbullet.com/#pushes

Comment: @christopherhesse
Awesome man. I'm obviously a beginniner. This is way easier to build than I thought it would be. Thanks for the suggestion. You should answer and I'll mark it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If they're coming from a script, you can pretty easily call the pushbullet api to send a push to your phone: https://docs.pushbullet.com/#pushes

If you use curl on the command line, it would look something like this:

```
curl --header 'Authorization: Bearer <your_access_token_here>' -X POST https://api.pushbullet.com/v2/pushes \
    --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
    --data-binary '{"type": "note", "title": "Note Title", "body": "Note Body"}'
```

If you're using python, you probably want to use the requests library, where it would look something like:

```
requests.post('https://api.pushbullet.com/v2/pushes',
    data=json.dumps({"type": "note", "title": "Note Title", "body": "Note Body"}), 
    headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer <access token>', 'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
```

You can find your access token on this page: https://www.pushbullet.com/account